# Check if files exist in case some files contain [ Bash

Tags: bash, file

I've got a set of files, let say

```
file1.txt
File2.txt
File [3].txt
file 4.txt
```

In my script, I store the path of each file in a var called $file.
Here is my issue:
in bash, testing the existence of it with following command

```
[[ ! -f "$file" ]]
```

WILL WORK (= system see that the file exists) for regular file like
file1.txt
File2.txt
file 4.txt BUT WILL NOT WORK (= system don't find the file - as it is not existing) with file containing [ ] in it, like File [3].txt does.

I assume it is because of the [ ] that interfer with the double [[. Testing with

```
test ! -f "$file"
```

is the same, system do not see it and return a missing file.

What can I do to escape the [ or to avoid such behaviour ? I've tried to find the solution on the net, but as I type "check if file exist with filename containing [" there is a bias as [ / [[ is used to check the existence..

Thanks for your help !

---

EDIT - 2022-01-15
Here is the loop I'm using

```
while read -r file; do
    if [[ ! -f "$file" ]]; then
        echo "Missing file $file"       
    fi
done < Compil.all ;
```

where Compil.all is a text file containing the path of file :

```
$cat Compil.all
/media/veracrypt1/file1.txt
/media/veracrypt1/File2.txt
/media/veracrypt1/File [3].txt
/media/veracrypt1/file 4.txt
$
```

AS I don't want to have issue with space in filenames, I've put the following code in the beginning of the script. Could it be the reason ?

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```

Comment: How do you iterate over the files? How are you reading the files. Please show the loop.

Comment: Testing that way should work (i.e. it detect files with square brackets in the name), and does when I test it. I suspect something is going wrong somewhere else; maybe the variable is not being set correctly. Try putting `set -x` before the problem section to turn on debug tracing, and see if that shows anything useful.

Comment: The `test` command should work. Chances are your script has a bug elsewhere. Try `printf -- "$file"` to make sure the `$file` variable has the value you think it does.

Comment: Thank you both for your comment. I've edited my question to add the loop I'm using.  `set -x` make me see that I'm overwriting IFS, maybe it comes from here ?

Comment: @Thibault I've replicated your setup and run your `while read -r file; do ...` script, it works for me. I'm wondering if you don't have a case sensitivity issue given that Veracrypt is a Windows software. Does the case in your file list match your actual file name case?

Comment: I've finally found the issue, which is human related and not tech related.. an extra blankspace in the filename `File  [3].txt` were in place, so that the file was INDEED not existing. System were right, the file is not existing.. Sorry for that mates !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you storing the `file` var?
Simply iterating works as shown below:

```
$ ls
 file1.txt   File2.txt  'File [3].txt'  'file 4.txt'
$ for file in ./* ;do if [[ -f "$file" ]];then echo $file; fi; done
./file1.txt
./File2.txt
./File [3].txt
./file 4.txt
```

This also works:

```
$ [[ ! -f "File [3].txt" ]]
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Nicolas. I've edited my question to post the complete loop where I check if the files exist.

Comment: I've tested it on my system (ubuntu 20.04) on the Terminal and I don't have the same result.. :/ `$[[ ! -f "File [3].txt" ]]` and then `$echo $?` returns  `0`

Comment: ok sorry.. tested and same result. Thank you. Thus my script contains error elsewhere so.

Comment: I've finally found the issue, which is human related and not tech related.. an extra blankspace in the filename `File  [3].txt` were in place, so that the file was INDEED not existing. System were right, the file is not existing.. Sorry for that mates !